# Manual creation of a confusion matrix

Tags: weka

How do I manually construct a confusion matrix from the below information

Instances:    6
Attributes:   33
              label
              crude
              demand
              for
              has
              in
              increased
              is
              of
              oil
              outstrips
              price
              short
              significantly
              supply
              the
              a
              bit
              cooking
              do
              flavor
              food
              frying
              like
              not
              oily
              olive
              pan
              people
              some
              use
              very
              was
    Test mode:   evaluate on training data

Comment: Come up with a model from training data to predict a logistic unknown, then run the test data through it to calculate predicted values.   You'll have expected yes/no, actual yes/no data.  Enter the frequency of each combination and you'll have your confusion matrix.

Comment: what do you mean by model from the training?  do you mean in weka?

Comment: No, any model that you create.  This is true in general; Weka is just one machine learning suite among many.